# Parallellizing N-Body simulation using openmp

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize Fortran  code  for N-body simulation  but it always takes longer execution time compared with the sequential version and the execution time increase with increasing the number of threads used for the parallelization .

I have tried to parallelize one subroutine at a time but the problem arises for each one of them I have tried using all reduction clause , Flush, Barrier to avoid  race condition in the arrays, but with no good result. Even in calculating the scalar potential energy the same problem arises. Even in parallelizing the time steps in the main file . There is something I don't understand  I hope you could help me.

```
module functions
    implicit none
    contains
  subroutine initial_speed(nb_particles,v,position)
     implicit none
     integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
     integer :: i, nb_particles
     real(kind=dp), ALLOCATABLE:: position(:,:) , omega(:,:) , v(:,:)
     !$OMP parallel shared(position,v) private(i)
    ! $OMP do schedule (dynamic)

     do i = 1, nb_particles 
        v(1, i) =  - position(2,i)
        v(2, i) =  position(1, i) 
        v(3, i) =  0
     end do
     !$OMP END DO
     !$OMP END PARALLEL
  end subroutine initial_speed

 subroutine acceleration(nb_particles,position,ai1,m,G )
     implicit none
     integer :: i,j,nb_particles
     integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
     real(kind=dp) :: G,m ,x ,y, z , r, dist(3)
     real(kind=dp), ALLOCATABLE:: position(:,:), ai1(:,:)
     ai1(:,:) =0.
     !$OMP parallel shared (position ,G,m,ai1) private(dist,i,j) 
      !$OMP do  schedule (DYNAMIC) reduction(+:ai1)
     do i= 1, nb_particles
        do j= i+1, nb_particles
             !  dist(1) = position(1,j) - position(1,i)
              ! dist(2) = position(2,j) - position(2,i)
              ! dist(3) = position(3,j) - position(3,i)
                dist(:) = position(:,j) - position(:,i)

                !ai1(1,i) =ai1(1,i) +(G*m*(x))/((sqrt(abs(r)**2+0.02**2))**3 )
                !ai1(2,i) = ai1(2,i)+(G*m*(y))/((sqrt(abs(r)**2+0.02**2))**3 )
                !ai1(3,i) = ai1(3,i)+(G*m*(z))/((sqrt(abs(r)**2+0.02**2))**3 )
               
                ai1(:,i) =ai1(:,i) +(G*m*(dist(:)))/(dot_product(dist,dist)+0.04**2)**1.5 
                ai1(:,j) =ai1(:,j) -(G*m*(dist(:)))/(dot_product(dist,dist)+0.04**2)**1.5
                              
        enddo
     enddo
    !$OMP END DO
      !$OMP END PARALLEL
    end subroutine acceleration


    subroutine leapfrog(nb_particles,position,v,dt,a,ai1,m,G)
     implicit none
     integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
     integer :: i ,nb_particles
     real(kind=dp) :: dt, G,m
     real(kind=dp), ALLOCATABLE:: position(:,:), v(:,:), a(:,:),ai1(:,:)
     call acceleration(nb_particles,position,a,m,G)
     !$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(position,a, dt) Private(i)
     !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC)
     do i = 1, nb_particles
         !position(1,i)=position(1,i)+v(1,i)*dt + 0.5*a(1,i)*(dt**2)
         !position(2,i)=position(2,i)+v(2,i)*dt + 0.5*a(2,i)*(dt**2)
         !position(3,i)=position(3,i)+v(3,i)*dt + 0.5*a(3,i)*(dt**2)
         position(:,i)=position(:,i)+v(:,i)*dt + 0.5*a(:,i)*(dt**2)
     end do
    !$OMP END DO 
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
     
     call  acceleration(nb_particles,position,ai1,m,G)
     
     !$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(v,a,ai1, dt) Private(i)
     !$OMP do schedule (Dynamic) 
          do  i = 1, nb_particles
         !v(1,i) = v(1,i) + 0.5 * (a(1,i)+ai1(1,i))*dt
         !v(2,i) = v(2,i) + 0.5 * (a(2,i)+ai1(2,i))*dt
         !v(3,i) = v(3,i) + 0.5 * (a(3,i)+ai1(3,i))*dt
          v(:,i) = v(:,i) + 0.5 * (a(:,i)+ai1(:,i))*dt
     end do
     !$OMP END DO 
     !$OMP END PARALLEL
     a = ai1

    end subroutine

    subroutine KE(kin_e,nb_particles,v,m)
        implicit none
        integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
        integer:: nb_particles,i
        real(dp) :: m, kin_e ,vv 
        real(dp), allocatable :: v(:,:)
         kin_e = kin_e + 0.5 * m * sum(v**2)
    end subroutine

    subroutine PE(pot,nb_particles,G,m,position)
      implicit none
      integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
      integer :: nb_particles, i, j 
      real(dp) :: G, m, pot,x,y,z ,r
      real(dp), allocatable :: position(:,:)
      pot = 0.0
      !$OMP PARALLEL SHARED (position) private(x,y,z,i,j)
      !$OMP DO SCHEDULE (dynamic) reduction(- : pot)
      do i = 1, nb_particles
         do j = i,nb_particles
            if (j/=i) then
              x = position(1,j)- position(1,i)
               y = position(2,j)- position(2,i)
               z = position(3,j)- position(3,i)

               pot = pot - (m**2)*G/ dsqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2 +0.04**2)
            end if
         enddo
      enddo
      !$OMP END DO
      !$OMP END PARALLEL
   end subroutine
```

```
  program nbody
    use functions
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    integer :: nb_particles=2000, radius, nb_steps=1000 ,t1,t2,rate
    real(dp):: x,y,z,r, G = 1 ,m, dt=0.01,kin_e=0.0,pot=0.0, time, dist(3)
    integer :: i,t = 0,j
    real(dp), ALLOCATABLE:: position(:,:)  , v(:,:), a(:,:), ai1(:,:), ai1_private(:,:)

    radius = 1
    G = 1.
    dt=0.01
    m = 1./real(nb_particles,kind=dp)
    open(unit=1, file='position_ini.txt', status='old', action='read')
    
    open(unit=100,file="Energy.txt")
    allocate(position(3,nb_particles)) 
    do i =1,nb_particles
        read(1,*) position(1,i), position(2,i), position(3,i)    
    enddo
    
    

    allocate(v(3,nb_particles))
    call initial_speed(nb_particles,v,position)
 
    allocate(a(3,nb_particles))    
    allocate(ai1(3,nb_particles))
 
   call KE(kin_e,nb_particles,v,m)
    call PE(pot,nb_particles,G,m,position)
    write(100,*) kin_e , pot , kin_e+pot, t*dt
  !  !$OMP parallel DO SCHEDULE(runtime)  private(t)
    do t = 1 , 1000
     call leapfrog(nb_particles,position,v,dt,a,ai1,m,G)
     call KE(kin_e,nb_particles,v,m)
     call PE(pot,nb_particles,G,m,position)
     write(100,*) kin_e , pot , kin_e+pot , t
    end do
    !!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
     
    close(100)
    close(1)
  

   


end program
```

edited

Here is the full code, I have used  `integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)` instead of `real(8)` , unparallelized the time stepping., also used `iso_fortran_env` but with no positive results.

I use gfortran compiler (gcc 11.4) with openmp 4.5. the CPU is i7 13600 H.  I measure the execution time using time command
Here is how i compile and run the program
 `gfortran main.f90 functions.f90 -fopenmp -O3  -o Nbody`

`time ./Nbody`

Comment: It would be much better if you provided a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we could compile and run to see if we can reproduce your problems. We *might* be able to guess something by staring at the code, but we can be much more definitive if we can test it. You are very close to such a thing, why not go the whole way?

Comment: Why have you nexted your parallel regions? i.e. a `parallel do` around the (unparallelisable) time stepping loop and *also* `parallel do` in the orphan subroutines. What happens i ou delete the completely unneeded `parallel do` around the time stepping loop? I would also drop dynamic scheduling at this stage.

Comment: Don't use real(8). It is not portable, not guaranteed to be supported by a compiler (and is not by some), if it is it might not do what you expect and is just plain bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter . I would recommend the `iso_fortran_env` method nowadays.

Comment: Why are you declaring your dummy arguments as `Allocatable` when you don't allocate them in the routines? Once allocated you can treat them just as normal arrays.

Comment: For such a question you have to provide more details: which hardware (in particular which CPU) you are running on, which compiler and which compilation options, how you are measuring the execution time, and the timings (without OpenMP, and with OpenMP on 1, 2, 4, 8... threads)

Comment: I have applied the  changes being suggested but no change in the results , I compare the sequential code without using `-fopenmp` and then comparing the execution time for 2,4,8,16 threads .. The details asked are in the edited post above

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, but some are still missing: the compilation options, the timings, and how you are measuring the time (Fortran doesn't have a "time command", so it's still unclear).

Comment: How the CPU, there doesn't exist a Core i7 13600H, it's either the core i5 13600H or the core i7 13700H. Either way, both have a mix of performant and efficient cores, and the usual OpenMP libraries are not very good at exploiting these configurations.

Comment: You are using the `dynamic` schedule, which in theory makes sense in the `acceleration` routine because the iterations are unbalanced. However, this schedule has more overheads and performances are often disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is not a magic wand that can speed-up everything, some algorithms do inherently not parallelize well. And when they do, there can be many reasons why an OpenMP code is not as fast as expected, or even slower than the serial code.

As stated in the comments, nested OpenMP regions are often not efficient, try avoiding that if not really necessary.

The total workload has to be large enough to get the benefits of the parallelization and hide the overheads. Maybe your code would scale better with more particles.

In your code you are using everywhere `schedule(dynamic)`, which is bad idea, in particular when the parallelized loop has a very low workload per iteration, as in `initial_speed()` and `leapfrog`: each thread executes only iteration at a time, and most of the time is spent distributing the iterations to the threads. Moreover in your code it results in false sharing, which is a performance killer. Unless you have a good reason to do so, do not change the default scheduling, which is `static`.

The only place where `schedule(dynamic)` can make sense is in the `acceleration()` routine because of the unbalanced iteration. However, even there it's not garanteed to be really effective. Maybe larger chunks than the default (which is 1) could help:
`SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,10)`

My experience in similar cases showed that starting with the iterations with the least workload and using the `guided` schedule was actually more efficient:

```
     !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(dist,i,j,tmp) 
     !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(GUIDED) REDUCTION(+:ai1)
     do i= nb_particles, 1, -1
        do j= i+1, nb_particles
           dist(:) = position(:,j) - position(:,i)
           tmp = G*m/(dot_product(dist,dist)+0.04**2)**1.5 
           ai1(:,i) = ai1(:,i) + tmp*dist(:) 
           ai1(:,j) = ai1(:,j) - tmp*dist(:)        
        enddo
     enddo
     !$OMP END DO
     !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

The reduction also possibly hurts the performances, as well as the fact that the inner loop is updating the whole `ai1(:,:)` array for each iteration of the outer loop, with some cache misses. You can avoid that by basically updating only `ai1(:,i)`, but you have then to scan the whole indeces in the inner loop. Some computations are done twice, but maybe it's a better approach for the parallelization. Another advantage is that the default schedule can be used (and no reduction is needed, as `ai1` can now be shared:

```
     !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(dist,i,j,tmp) 
     !$OMP DO
     do i= 1, nb_particles
        do j= 1, nb_particles
           dist(:) = position(:,j) - position(:,i)
           tmp = G*m/(dot_product(dist,dist)+0.04**2)**1.5 
           ai1(:,i) = ai1(:,i) + tmp*dist(:) 
        enddo
     enddo
     !$OMP END DO
     !$OMP END PARALLEL
```